# Consulta MySql con PHP

Tags: mysql

Tengo 2 tablas: Estudiantes y Prestamos_Libros.  la tabla Prestamos_Libros tiene un campo de estado con tres posibilidades, 1, 2 y 3.

la tabla Estudiantes tiene 15.000 registros, de los cuales 259 registros pertenecen al grupo 10.  Puedo listar los estudiantes del grupo 10 que tienen libros prestados (estado 1 y 3), son 127, pero requiero saber los estudiantes del grupo 10 que no tienen prestado libros ( es decir estado 2).

Comment: Edita tu pregunta y pon el código de la consulta que realizas para saber que es lo que tienes hasta ahora.

Comment: Entiendo tu necesidad pero no veo ninguna pregunta. Es más, sabes lo que debes hacer y creo que tienes una idea de cómo hacerlo. Por favor edita tu pregunta para que reflejes cuál es el problema que tienes o por qué te encuentras atascado.

Comment: PHP es irrelevante aquí

Comment: Hace falta una mayor descripción de las relaciones entre las tablas. Por lo poco que menciona, es posible que la tabla Estudiantes esté relacionada 1 a muchos con Prestamos_Libros, por lo que haciendo un join entre las dos y un group by bastaría, pero sin datos concretos sólo hay respuestas muy en el aire.

Comment: El problema que tengo es que requiero listar únicamente los estudiantes del grupo 10 que no tienen libros prestados, son 132, pero no me funciona la consulta.

Comment: Como ya te han comentado, sería útil que editaras la pregunta e incluyeras el código de la consulta.

Answer (score 1):

Tu pregunta no deja muy clara tu duda, pero a lo poco que he entendido si en el grupo 10 en total hay 259 registros.

dices que tu tabla Prestamos libros tiene 3 estados (1,2,3) y si puedes listar los registros que tienen libros prestados, estados (1 y 3) a lo que te da 127.

si dices que el estado 2 corresponde a libros no prestados, simplemente al total de registros "259" le restas "127" que corresponde a los libros prestados, estados 1 y 3, lo cual te dará los registros del estado 2.

dicha consulta la haces de la misma forma en que consultaste los libros prestados, incluso mas simple.

pero en todo caso para una respuesta clara necesitas presentar tu consulta y estructura de tablas como ya te han comentado.

Answer (score 0):

Tendrías que poner la estructura de las tablas, para saber exactamente como se relacionan los libros prestados con los estudiantes, ya que dependiendo de la relación, la consulta se hace de una o de otra manera